# ASP.NET[Web-Forms]: Check All Checkboxes in Listview Nested within another Listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, checkbox, nested

I have the following scenario:

```
[ ] Supervisor 1
    [ ] Employee 1
    [ ] Employee 2
    [ ] Employee 3

[ ] Supervisor 2
    [ ] Employee 7
    [ ] Employee 8
```

Assuming [ ] represents a CheckBox, what I want to do is if I check the CheckBox next to (Supervisor 1) I want only the Checkboxes next to (Employees 1, 2, 3) to be checked and if I check the CheckBox next to (Supervisor 2) I want to check only checkboxes (Employee 7, and 8)

```
<asp:ListView ID="SupervisorsListView" runat="server" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSupervisor" runat="server" />

        <asp:ListView ID="EmployeesListViews" runat="server" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEmployee" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

I need to achieve this in client side preferably using jQuery, can anyone give me a hint on how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use it using Tree view

Try this 
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview/treeview

Also you will need to do some coding to match your exact requirement.